# Is it worth to try to reward post improvements with different score?

Tags: support, review, suggested-edits

Many revisions simply add a few grammar corrections. Some others adds also links, tags and improve formatting.

Could it be useful if the system would be able measure<sup>1</sup> the effort put into improving the questions / answers and reward it raising the reputation accordingly?

Strong collaborative improvements lead Wikipedia to a great success<sup>2</sup>.

*Collaborative review effort expected for this question **:-p***

### Proposal

- <strike>After 2000 reputation it's ideal to edit every mistake you can see without having to wait for approval</strike> This is already the case

### Criticism and questions

- An interesting idea but ***it would be hard to judge what a reward amount would be***.
- <strike>Reward how? Rep? Badges? Unicorns? Something entirely different?</strike> => reputation
- Let's narrow the proposal: What reward? How to measure?

---

<sup>1. There needs a definition for this metric which should measure effort

2. According to Wikipedia, the company’s value rose 4000% during its tenure

3. See [edit privilege on meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit)</sup>

Comment: Reward how?  Rep? Badges? Unicorns? Something entirely different?

Comment: An interesting idea but it would be hard to judge what a reward amount would be.

Comment: @psubsee2003: let's show collaboration, improve my question yourself! Consider it wikified. It's not important who had opened it.

Comment: Yes it's worth trying but right now it's way too broad. What reward? How to measure?

Comment: @DaImTo: are we scared by challenges? I guess no!

Comment: I think a revision should not add +2 reputation if only changed a dot or comma somewhere. After 2000 reputation it's ideal to edit every mistake you can see without having to wait for approval (not resulting in +2, but that doesn't matter) -- Tags are important on the other hard IMO

Comment: @ShadowWizard: I've got many simple ideas on that, but let's try to edit my original question. Let's try to make it collaboratively.

Comment: @Rob: I agree, edit my question if you like! Let's make an experiment. Start from this post. See how it becomes by collaborative edits.

Comment: I edit to fix tagging issues often.  IMO they improve the chance of the question being answered quite a bit.

Comment: @DaImTo That;s important IMO as stated above

Comment: Regarding the proposal you have suggested: [please see](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit)

Comment: @hjpotter92 I've tried 4 times to add the edit, but it changed 3 times without showing up as my change. Maybe we can sew revisions together?

Comment: @Rob I [rejected it once](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/26302) myself because you're trying to change the idea as proposed by the OP. The post is not marked as a Community Wiki and hence, you shouldn't tinker too much with its content.

Comment: @hjpotter92 I can ensure you that I only added <strike>strikes</strike>. So 2 edits mixed up! I did not remove everything from the original post. I'd like to file a bug.

Comment: @hjpotter92: for me it's ok to mark it as a community wiki, but I cannot do on my own. Someone can help me?

Comment: @Revious Flag your own thread > other > state clearly that you want it converted to CW and why!