# Increase the quality of suggested edits

Tags: feature-request, review, edits, suggested-edits

Please review the duplicate again. I think this question is not a duplicate.

---

I was thinking about a way to improve the quality of suggested edits.

I even more often than sometimes find myself wanting to improve the suggested edit.

Editing can be quick and easy, but it can be also a little bit time consuming.

**How about rewarding good suggested edits?**

I was thinking that there could be a check box saying *Good edit* (or so) and, when the reviewer thinks that the edit was good and/or some effort had been made, he/she could check that box when approving. Checking that box could give some reputation to the editor of the question.

I tend to believe that this could improve the quality of the edits in general since there is an incentive to do it better.

---

The editors get +2 reps for an approved suggested edit. However, I think there is still quality that can be improved. The +2 reps can be an incentive for someone to go and edit. Now I was thinking to reward those who put a bit more effort and do a *proper* edit without discouraging them with a reject. This could lead to less rejected edits and hopefully more quality suggested edits, and we would need to press the *Improve edit* button less often too.

Comment: More rep than the +2?

Comment: If it is a good edit done with some effort, why not? Maybe it could add +1 more. It might look minor, but when you edit a couple of times you could get a little bit more reputation out of that. Could be an incentive I think.

Comment: I think a checkbox that reduces the +2 to +1 (or even 0) for edits of marginal value would be a more valuable enhancement.

Comment: @PolyGeo For example yes. But then I see difficulties. Users are used to +2 reps. +1 rep could represent less of an incentive and could be understood as a *penalty*. I prefer to reward and encourage in general.

Comment: @random I don't think that this is a duplicate of said question. I updated my question. Hopefully it is clearer now.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/227595/is-it-worth-to-try-to-reward-post-improvements-with-different-score http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/121454/how-can-we-encourage-more-substantial-suggested-edits http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/169690/require-substantial-edits-when-editing

Comment: I like to encourage editing that improves a post even slightly, and +2 seems fair for a substantial edit.  However, it begrudges me to award +2 pts for a 2 second edit.  To award more than +2 for even a substantial edit seems too much in relation to the 5/10 points for acknowledging good questions/answers.

Comment: Thanks @random - Though my thinking is the following: The first question asks for a different scoring scheme. It's closely related, yet the discussion goes a different path. The second is also closely related, but proposes different mechanisms (not mentioning rewards or reps as gamification or incentive). The third one is more substantial, it is also about concurrent edits, and thus leading to a different discussion too. Mine is about a feature request to add a bit more of gamification to motivate users to better edits.

Comment: It's getting less clear the more you clarify. Are you saying there should be a system to award more than +2 based on a checkbox that says it should be more?

Comment: @random You closed a feature-request as a dupe of an FAQ 0_o

Comment: @random Basically yes. I was thinking maybe this could be a good idea. The +2 reps are an incentive to take the time and edit. I was looking for a way to incentivate someone to take the time and make a good edit. If the edit is qualified as good by the reviewer, then the reviewer can reward the editor by clicking that checkbox and thus the editor get +1 more for example.

Comment: To me, this feels like you should just follow the "Improve edit" route and fix whatever else needs fixing...

Comment: @Werner that's what I mean. If we could help the users do better editing, so that we press that button *Improve edit* less often, that would be great i think.

Answer (score 1):

> I was thinking that there could be a check box saying Good edit (or
>   so) and, when the reviewer thinks that the edit was good and/or some
>   effort had been made, he/she could check that box when approving.

Perhaps I've misunderstood you, but isn't this already the case?
When users approve a suggested edit, the user who suggested it gets a historical log in their profile of "approved".

Is there something additional you meant? Or somewhere else you suggest the "good edit" ("approved") is displayed?

> Checking that box could give some reputation to the editor of the
>   question.

2 rep is already given for this, up to a user having 2000 rep.

---

I think the current rewards are ok as they are.
People suggest edits, they get some rep if it's a good edit, and the site is improved.

You have to be careful, and not reward "too much", as that can lead to bad suggested edits because the "reward" is very enticing.
There has to be a certain element of doing it for the sake of the site.

---

**Edit** to reply to your edit:

> I was thinking to reward those who put a bit more effort and do a
>   proper edit without discouraging them with a reject.

This could be potentially a good thing, but what reward, how, why?
I'm not saying there's no potential, but you don't seem to suggest anything.
What reward should they get?
If there is a lower reward (basic edits) and higher reward (better edits), how is the reward decided, by who?

However you do this, it's likely going to have to be through the review queue, and I don't think reviewers should be deciding if a user should have more reward or not.
Reviewers should be deciding if edit is good or bad, worthy of "approve" or "reject".

Reward should be decided upon by the site based on how the system is working, if it needs tweaking, are too many users editing because of the reward, if so reduce it, etc.

Again, there are possibilities, but it's going to have to be a very specific and well thought out idea.

Because when you segregate users and reward them differently from each other for essentially doing the same tasks, you risk having users disheartened/annoyed/arguing from not getting the same reward as their fellow users for putting in the same effort, or more.
This also brings the potential for users stopping suggesting edits, because they feel it's unfair they usually only get a smaller reward when other users get more when their suggested edits where trivial, or poor.
Or worse, the user who got less reward was actually fixing many things in a 
post which the user who got a higher reward missed out.

Essentially, there would be a fair few users who end up with the gooey end of the stick, and it aint chocolate...

---

Personally I think rather than award *more* for better edits, we should penalise those who make many trivial and rejected edits.
Then those who are editing and making an effort are getting their *deserved* 2 rep, and those not making an effort get nothing.

Sure, this causes a potential for less reviews, but as long as users only lose edit rep because of serious or lots of bad edits, then who cares if they stop editing?
It wasn't long ago I got 2k On Stack Overflow, and started reviewing suggested edits frequently.
I was quite shocked at the number of not only really poor edit suggestions, but terrible reviewing too.
Approving changes to code in *questions* which implement the fix for the very thing they're asking about.

I think it should be stricter, as we have enough users now that I think getting rid of some of the bad reviewers and users making poor suggestions wouldn't be detrimental to the site.

Now, *how* that is done is the difficult question.
Make it too strict, and you are unfair on good users. If it's not strict enough, then it's not doing anything worthwhile.

Comment: I edited my question. It is about improved the quality of submitted suggested edits and reduce the rejects.